# UltraESB when run from netbeans IDE gives "service not found" error in ultraesb soa toolbox but works fine when run from cmd

Tags: esb, ultraesb, adroitlogic

The following is default proxy service in ultraesb file "ultra-unit.xml"

```
<u:proxy id="echo-proxy">
        <u:transport id="http-8280"/>
        <u:target>
        <u:inSequence>
                <u:class name="sample.SimpleJavaMediation1"/>
        </u:inSequence>
        <u:inDestination>
                <u:address>http://localhost:9000/service/EchoService</u:address>
        </u:inDestination>
        <u:outSequence>
                <u:java><![CDATA[
                        System.out.println("Reply payload : " + mediation.readPayloadAsString(msg));
                    ]]></u:java>
        </u:outSequence>
        <u:outDestination>
                <u:address type="response"/>
        </u:outDestination>
        </u:target>
 </u:proxy>
```

I run ultraesb from Netbeans IDE and run toolbox.bat from command line (as there is no other way to run toolbox). When i send message to "http://localhost:8280/service/echo-proxy" using Ultraesb toolbox, it gives me following error

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 13 Jun 2016 07:34:40 GMT
Server: UltraESB/2.3.0 (GA)
Content-Length: 17
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: close

Service not found

BUT when i run ultraesb.bat and toolbox.bat from commandline cmd....the service is perfectly accessed in toolbox and no error appears....
I really cant understand whats the issue...
Toolbox doesnt have log file whereas ultraesb log file exists which doesnt have any exception....no exception appears on Netbeans IDE console also. Please Help.

Comment: What is the version of UltraESB you are using?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your description it seems like the proxy service has not been deployed over the 8280 transport listener, as there doesn't seem to be any error logs on the UltraESB log. This could happen if the deployment unit is not deployed. NetBeans IDE configuration on the standalone distribution of UltraESB ships with 2 run profiles of UltraESB one for the default server, another for the samples. If you are running the sample run profile it doesn't by default deploy the deployment units.

You got to either run the default server run profile or enable the deployment units in the environment bean of the ultra-root.xml. For more information on the NetBeans IDE setup please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.adroitlogic.org/ultraesb/v2_3/user-guide/#_setting_up_netbeans)